# iPhone: Efficiently downloading images from a URL into iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my iPhone app , I need to display the images from server.

I need to download it and save it from URLs.

There are roughly 20 images which I need to download.

What could be a way out where in performance doesnt decrease?

I have tried previously using NSData to convert the images into NSData and saving it to my app but it takes lots of time.

What could be a more easier and efficient way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using ASIHTTPRequest to download the images asynchronously, and display them when they're ready.  By using the asynchronous interface of that class, your app can be responsive and continue to operate normally while, in the background, you wait for the data to be loaded.

ASIHTTPRequest is open source and free to use: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: Why? What benefits does ASIHTTPRequest over NSURLRequest?

Answer (score 2):

The code the Facebook app uses to download and display images has been open-sourced as part of [the three20 library](http://three20.info/).

If you want to write your own networking code [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is a very useful library that includes features such as downloading directly to a file and queue management.